# TSQL: Drop Temp Table Gives Error When Scehma Changes

Tags: t-sql

This has been bugging me for a while, so finally decided to understand why it happened. Any version of SQL server 2005 on

I have a query I'm developing like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ProdOrders') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [#ProdOrders];

CREATE TABLE [#ProdOrders]
(
    [Document No_] NVARCHAR(20)
    ,[Item No_] NVARCHAR(20)
    ,[PlannedQty] INT
);

    INSERT INTO [#ProdOrders]
         (
             [Document No_]
             ,[Item No_]
             ,[PlannedQty]
         )
    
    Select ...
```

Now I Decide to add a column, so I change it to this (in same session)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ProdOrders') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [#ProdOrders];

CREATE TABLE [#ProdOrders]
    (
        [Document No_] NVARCHAR(20)
        ,[Item No_] NVARCHAR(20)
        ,[PlannedQty] INT
        ,[Facility] NVARCHAR(2)
    );

    INSERT INTO [#ProdOrders]
         (
             [Document No_]
             ,[Item No_]
             ,[PlannedQty]
             ,[Facility]
         )
    
    Select...
```

When I execute it, I get an error saying the new column (Facility) is unknown

Anyone got any idea why?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: You submitted the statements as a single batch so they are processed together. That means that query plan for the `insert` statement is created using the existing, not new, table schema. In SSMS you can separate batches with [`go`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15), e.g between the table changes and the `insert`. Other interfaces have different methods, e.g in .NET you might use two `SqlCommand` instances to execute the two batches.

Comment: @habo  thanks for reply. It's not one batch. I execute a statement, change the sql, execute again. That's 2 batches. Sorry of that wasn;t clear from the post

Comment: If you hand SQL Server everything from `IF OBJECT_ID(...)` though `Select...` at one time, e.g. in an SSMS query window, _that_ is one batch. If `#ProdOrders` as it exists _before_ execution starts is not compatible with the `insert` statement then the batch will fail. Executing the four statements in two separate batches of two statements each (`IF...`, `CREATE TABLE...` and `INSERT...`, `Select...`) will solve the problem. Try it in SSMS with `go` before the `insert`: run it, change the DDL for the table and run it again.

Comment: @habo got ya. Makes sense now